# lodash filter map, array of object containing dates and formatting to MM/DD

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am trying to use lodash to map and filter an array of object containing dates like

```
[{date: '2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00'},{date: '2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00'},{date: '2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00'}]
```

I am trying to achieve

```
['09/15', 09/15', '09/15']
```

I tried

```
const formated dates = this.states.data.filter(o => moment(o.date)).format('MM/DD'))
```

also tried something like this

```
const dates = _.map(
 _.filter(o => moment(o.date)).format('MM/DD'))
)
```

but so far, unsuccessful.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is to parse your date, after that, things get easier

```
2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSZZ
```

(for more detail on tokens, check the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/))

```js
const data = [
  { date: "2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00" },
  { date: "2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00" },
  { date: "2020-09-15T04:43:15:2176807-04:00" },
]

const res = _(data)
  .map("date")
  .map((date) => moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSZZ").format("MM/DD"))
  .value()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```